# Show number of days given a start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to write a T-SQL query that will list out the number of days given a start and end date. For example:

- Start Date - 1/15/2014
- End Date - 3/15/2014

Results would look like this:

```
Jan 2014 | Feb 2014 | March 2014
---------------------------------- 
  15     |    28    |     15
```

Comment: Okay, so what T-SQL have you written to try and accomplish this? Please edit your question with what you've tried.

Comment: To clarify: in your results, shouldn't January's number be 16, since there are 31 days in the month? (assuming you're counting the number of days left in the month from the start date)

Comment: do you already have a calendar table?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not great at "creating" data - meaning if you need to get a list of dates (or months) between two dates then SQL essentially has to loop and create the data one row at a time.

If this is a common pattern, you will benefit greatly by creating a physical table that stores each date as a row and various metadata about that date (month, year, weekday, week of year, etc.) – what is otherwise known as a *calendar table*.

(You could also fabricate one with a CTE or other mechanism but having a physical table will likely be much faster)

Assuming you have such a table, the query would just be:

```
SELECT Month,COUNT(*)
FROM Dates
WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above regarding counting the days for the first month.  I made an assumption that you want to return the number of remaining days in the month beginning from the start date.  Here's a loop to accomplish this, using test dates:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate    DATE = '1/15/2014',
        @EndDate      DATE = '3/15/2015',
        @CurrentMonth INT = 0

DECLARE @MonthCounter INT = DATEDIFF(Month, @BeginDate, @EndDate) + 1
DECLARE @Results TABLE (DateValue DATE, NumberOfDays INT)

WHILE @CurrentMonth < @MonthCounter
BEGIN

    IF @CurrentMonth = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT @Results
            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,@CurrentMonth,@BeginDate) AS DateValue,
                DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@CurrentMonth,@BeginDate))) - DAY(@BeginDate) AS NumberOfDays
        END
    ELSE IF @CurrentMonth = @MonthCounter - 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT @Results
            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,@CurrentMonth,@BeginDate) AS DateValue,
                DAY(@EndDate) AS NumberOfDays
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT @Results
            SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,@CurrentMonth,@BeginDate) AS DateValue,
                DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,@CurrentMonth,@BeginDate))) AS NumberOfDays
        END

    SET @CurrentMonth = @CurrentMonth + 1

END

SELECT DATENAME(Month,DateValue) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(DateValue)) AS [Month], NumberOfDays
FROM @Results
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS datetime = '20140115';
DECLARE @EndDate AS datetime = '20140315';

WITH DatesBetweenStartAndEnd AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
  UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, [Date])
    FROM DatesBetweenStartAndEnd
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
)
SELECT DATENAME(month, [YearMonth]) + ' ' + DATENAME(year, [YearMonth])
      ,COUNT(*)
FROM DatesBetweenStartAndEnd
     CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1-DAY([Date]), [Date]) AS [YearMonth] 
     ) AS CA1
GROUP BY [YearMonth]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```